# スピーチ認識APIで文字起こしは出来ないのでしょうか

Tags: aibo-developer

今は登録されている短いコマンドの認識しかできないようですが、aiboに向けた発話を認識して文字に変換する機能はありませんか。

質問を整理できなかった事によってご迷惑をおかけして申し訳ありません。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 質問者は、誰を対象にして質問しているのですか？
それとも、単に感想を他人に知らせたいだけなのですか？
「マスト」と思うのは、誰が、どういる判断基準で、具体的に何（どんな機能）が必要だと言っているのですか？「とか」という曖昧なものに基づいた質問は、具体的な、あるいは精緻な回答を期待していないとの表明ですよね。
で、質問の意図は何なんですか？？？？？

Comment: @Fumu7 ご迷惑をかけて申し訳ございません。訂正しました。

Answer (score 0):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

> 今は登録されている短いコマンドの認識しかできないようですが、aiboに向けた発話を認識して文字に変換する機能はありませんか。

現時点で aibo への発話の認識結果をそのまま通知する API は公開しておりません。
aibo が任意の言葉に反応するようにするには、認識ワードの登録をお使いください。

**aibo デベロッパーサイト　認識ワードの登録**
https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E8%AA%8D%E8%AD%98%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2

> 認識ワードの登録
> aibo が反応する言葉（認識ワード）として、好きな言葉を登録することができます。登録した言葉は、イベント通知で利用したり、他の認識ワードと同様に aibo が反応した音声認識の結果を取得する API で取得したりすることができます。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム